# Error while trying to connect to HTTP server with netcat

Tags: nginx, http

I am trying to connect to the Nginx server which is running on my localhost at port 80 using netcat. But I am getting the same error page all the time inspite of whichever header(GET, POST, HEAD) i send. Can somebody explain me why ?

```
pradeep@pradeep-laptop:~$ echo -n "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n" | nc localhost 80
<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.1.19</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I am running the same above command but still i am getting the html page.

```
pradeep@pradeep-laptop:~$ echo -n "HEAD / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n" | nc localhost 80
<html>
<head><title>400 Bad Request</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>400 Bad Request</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.1.19</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I checked whether my nginx server is running or not using netstat command also. The output is as follows:

```
root@pradeep-laptop:/# netstat -taupen| grep LISTEN | grep :80
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN          0          264102      13723/nginx
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`echo` (in bash and `/bin/echo`) don't expand escapes by default. This means that your CR and LF characters are literally being sent as `\r` and `\n`. You need to provide the `-e` option in order to enable escapes.

```
$ echo -en "GET / HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n" | nc localhost 80
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
```